# Hibernate Session Application Management

Tags: hibernate, session

I am using Hibernate (4.3.5) in a Web java project, what you be the best practices in the following case:

I have a object in application session, the logged in user, and this user have some Lazy objects inside. When i try to use the this User lazy properties within another Hibernate session (currentSession), i get a LazyInitializationException.

Should i reattach this user to the CurrentSession in my filter (So i can always use any of its lazy properties), change my user object load strategy to fetch all properties (just in this select that places the object in the app session), or what?

More info: My hibernate session scope is thread, and i initialize it and its transaction inside a HttpFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, attach it to the hibernate session and call methods on it for it to load lazy properties.

```
session.lock() if the transient object is not changed. 
session.update() if the transient object is changed
```

these above methods will attach the transient object to a session.

Comment: They are deprecated. Shouldn't i use another strategie?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: 4.3 (last version). I found a different way to do the lock, same thing with new methods...

sessao.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(usuarioLogado);

This sucessfully reattached the object in session without problem

Thanks